# Using delegates to reference objects from parent controls, methods vs. properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, delegates

In a typical webforms architecture, I have `UserControls` or server controls that need context information from their parent. In the past I've typically set a public property of the child control from the parent, but time of object availability can make this a nuisance in some situations. That is, I can't set the child property until the object exists at the parent, and I am using lazy loading typically. And I'd rather just not have to worry about asp.net page event lifecycle concerns.

So I've set up some forms using delegates instead which is seems much better, e.g.

```
//child object
public Func<SomeObject> ParentContext;

// parent object
override OnInit()
{
    ChildObject.ParentContext = Context;
}
public SomeObject Context() 
{
}
```

This makes it really easy to ensure that every child object has a valid reference, and leaves instantiation/lazy loading/whatever up to the root object.

Two questions:

1. Is this a good architecture? I have only just starting doing it and it seems to solve a lot of problems, but before I start making lots of things this way, I was hoping for some feedback.
2. Is there any way to do this with property get accessors that is just as easy, without using reflection? That is, in order to access the object from the delegate, since it's a function, I'm doing stuff like:

`var x = ParentContext().Property`

Is there a construct like `Func` that refers to properties, or to a get accessor? E.g. can I do something like:

```
// child
public PropertyGet<SomeObject> ParentContext;

// parent
override OnInit()
{
     ChildObject.ParentContext = Context.GetAccessor;
}
public SomeObject Context {
   get;set;
}
```

I know I can use reflection and `Delegate.CreateDelegate` to obtain a delegate to a property, but this would kind of defeat the purpose. I'm trying to simplify things and not add more overhead. I could also use the methods that I delegate to simply refer to the properties as well, but then I have to create both a property and a method for each thing in the parent and child.

Basically, is there any equivalent to `Func<>` that acts like a property?

Comment: What is the control trying to accomplish?

Comment: Not really important, it could be anything, the point is that a given child control needs to access an object that is owned by the parent.

Comment: For properties, you say you are currently doing `var x = ParentContext().Property`.  Then you ask for how to do it differently.  Can you provide a sample of how you would like that to look?  I'm not really following what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: I want it to look like `var x = ParentContext.Property`. I want to be able to access `properties` directly, not just methods.